# Can multiple $scope variables be passed in HTTP post request in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
  $scope.getQuery = function() {
    var response =  $http.post('/test/getQuery', $scope.query, $scope.algoName);
    response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           console.log($scope.query);           
           console.log($scope.algoName);
        });
   }
```

Here I am passing `$scope.query`, `$scope.algoName`. Is this possible in AngularJS?

Comment: what is that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass them in as the `data` paramater that `$http.post()` accepts:

```
var data = {
    query: $scope.query,
    algoName: $scope.algoName
};

$scope.getQuery = function() {
    var response =  $http.post('/test/getQuery', data);
    response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log($scope.query);
        console.log($scope.algoName);
    });
};
```

These will then be sent as the request message data.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.getQuery = function() {    
    var data = {    
        query: $scope.query,   
        algoName: $scope.algoName   
    };

    var response =  $http.post('/test/getQuery', data);

    response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log($scope.query);
        console.log($scope.algoName);
    });
};
```

Your data  variable need to in your function... may be he is call a function directly....

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason you need this requirement? It a usually requirement to build you data response object before sending

```
var data = {}
data.query = $scope.query;
data.algoName = $scope.algoName;

var response =  $http.post('/test/getQuery', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular's [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) accepts up to 3 parameters.

From the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

> post(url, data, [config]);

the `data` could be anything you want to pass to the url you can basically do this:

```
$scope.getQuery = function() {
    // your endpoint
    var endpoint = '/test/getQuery';

    // data you want to sent the server
    var data = {
        query: $scope.query,
        algoName: $scope.algoName
    };

    // all your configs
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' // or whatever you need here
        }
    };

    // This makes the call, the .then deals with the promise
    // the first function is success and the second deals with fail
    $http.post(endpoint, data, config).then(function(response) {
        console.debug(response);
    }, function (error) {
        console.debug(error);
    });
};
```

Another approach can be saving it in a variable, then resolving it I prefer using the first way, but if you want to pass it around that's another way of doing it.

```
var response = $http.post(endpoint, data, config);

response.then(function(response) {
    console.debug(response);
}, function (error) {
    console.debug(error);
});
```

Remember that `$hhtp` returns a promise, and the `.then` is how you resolve it, and extract the deferred information.